# How can I assign this description to every image when saving?

Tags: 7, forms, media

I am trying to display description field for every picture that is uploaded to the image gallery, at the moment I am able to upload as many pictures as I want and I display them with a description textarea using form like this:

```
  foreach($pictures as $key => $item){
    //dpm($item);
   $variables = array(
      'path' => $item,
      'alt' => 'Something went wrong',
      'title' => 'Image',
      'width' => '200px',
      'height' => '200px',
      'attributes' => array('class' => 'some-img', 'id' => 'my-img'),
    );
   //dpm($variables);
   $form['image-entry'][$key] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset'
    );
  $form['image-entry'][$key]['image'] = array(
      '#markup' => theme('image', $variables),
    );
  $form['image-entry'][$key]['description'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#attributes' => array(
        'placeholder' => t('Describe this picture'),
      ),
    );
  }
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Add more photos',
  );
  $form['#submit'][] = '_image_gallery_photos_add';
  return $form;
}
```

My question is, how can I save description to the corresponding image? Is there some kind of indexing that I can use? Maybe use `$key` variable somehow? I am kinda new to this, so please bear with me and thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not add a description field to your entity or content type?

Comment: @Avibodha In my entity I have 1 table called image_gallery_gallery which stores information on gallery itself (id, uid, created, changed, description). Then I have second table called image_gallery_photos which stores information on photos (id, gallery_id, full_path and img_description). As you can see I do have this field in my photos table, but I am not sure how can I take these values passed to the form and assign them to correct images.

Comment: In your _image_gallery_photos_add() are you not able to access the description element when form submitted? Or is the problem that it is not showing on the form itself?

Comment: @Avibodha if I `dpm($form_state)` on submit method, in the values I get only last description, meaning that it is overiding it.